# Django url warning urls.W002

Tags: python, django, url

Sorry in advance if this question look a bit superfluous but is something that is really bothering me.

I have a set of API's written in Django defined by the following urls.

```
# urls.py
import ...
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^api/v1/account", include(profile.urls))
]
```

and

```
# profile/urls.py
import ...
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^$", AccountAPI.as_view()),
    url(r"^/login$", LoginAPI.as_view()),
    url(r"^/logout$", LogoutAPI.as_view())
]
```

This configuration should allow **only** the urls:

```
/api/v1/account
/api/v1/account/login
/api/v1/account/logout
```

This work for my purpose but I keep having warnings like(I have several API defined with this rule and the warning list is way bigger):

```
?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '^/login$' has a regex beginning with a '/'. Remove this slash as it is unnecessary.
?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '^/logout$' has a regex beginning with a '/'. Remove this slash as it is unnecessary.
```

If I remove the **slash** the server will not validate the urls I defined. For that I have to had a **slash** to the first level of the urls like:

```
# urls.py
import ...
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^api/v1/account/", include(profile.urls))
]
```

And this will make the account call to end with a slash, something I don't want to.

I feel that I have defined the urls the most elegant way I found to serve my purpose and I keep having this sad warnings in my logs.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a right way to define the url's without compromising the structure I choose for them? Or there's a way of turning this warnings off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I wrote the check, I incorrectly assumed urls with trailing slashes, like `/api/v1/account/` and `/api/v1/account/login/`.

If you do not use trailing slashes, then starting an included url pattern with `^/` can be correct, and the `W002` check gives a false positive.

As of [Django 1.10.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10.2/), the check is disabled if you have `APPEND_SLASH=False` in your settings. See [ticket 27238](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27238) for the discussion.

Answer (score 11):

You can turn the warning(s) off using `SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS` option.

Example:

```
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['urls.W002', 'security.W019']
```

Answer (score 0):

> this will make the account call to end with a slash, something I don't want to.

Why? Is there any specific reason?

As far as Django is concerned, there's nothing *incorrect* in ending a url with a slash. Moreover, Django's admin urls end in a slash. [Django polls tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view) also appends slash to root URLconfs.

If you read [URL Dispacher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#example) example, it says:

> There’s no need to add a leading slash, because every URL has that. For example, it’s **^articles**, not **^/articles**.

Comment: Because I define it without. Personally, I prefer without. I read the URL dispatcher and that seems to be valid for the root url, not the ones "included" in the root.